# Reverse for 'password_change' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['r^password_change/$']

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I added django.contrib.auth authentication views to my app. Now I am unable to access these views. I am getting the error as mentioned in the title above. Do I have to remove the namespace or change the namespace to other name?

urls.py :

```
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from . import views

app_name = 'set_goals'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/about/$',views.about,name='about'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/download/$', views.download, name='download'),
    url(r'^login_user/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    url(r'^logout_user/$', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url('r^password_change/$',auth_views.password_change,{'post_change_redirect':'set_goals:password_change_done'},name='password_change')

,
url('r^password_change/done/$',auth_views.password_change_done,name='password_change_done'),
]
```

base.html :

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'set_goals:about' user.id %}">All Goals</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'set_goals:password_change' %}">Change Password</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'set_goals:logout_user' %}">Logout ({{user.username}})</a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'set_goals:index' %}">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'set_goals:login_user' %}">Login</a>
        </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'set_goals:register' %}">SignUp</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
```

what is the mistake here? what is the change to be done here? Please help. Thanks in Advance!

Error StackTrace :

```
    NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'password_change' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['r^password_change/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.0.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'password_change' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['r^password_change/$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\Akhil\PycharmProjects\GoalsProject\goals_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 636
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Akhil\PycharmProjects\GoalsProject\goals_env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Akhil\\PycharmProjects\\GoalsProject\\GoalsProject',
 'C:\\Users\\Akhil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'F:\\models',
 'F:\\models\\research',
 'F:\\models\\research\\slim',
 'F:\\models\\research\\object_detection',
 'C:\\Users\\Akhil\\PycharmProjects\\GoalsProject\\GoalsProject',
 'C:\\Users\\Akhil\\PycharmProjects\\GoalsProject\\goals_env\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Akhil\\PycharmProjects\\GoalsProject\\goals_env\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Akhil\\PycharmProjects\\GoalsProject\\goals_env\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Akhil\\PycharmProjects\\GoalsProject\\goals_env\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Users\\Akhil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Akhil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Akhil\\PycharmProjects\\GoalsProject\\goals_env',
 'C:\\Users\\Akhil\\PycharmProjects\\GoalsProject\\goals_env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 3 Aug 2018 02:53:23 +0000
```

The line in base.html with password_change view is displayed as error.

Comment: Can you please add the `views.py`?

Comment: also, add the error traceback too

Comment: in views.py, there is no code for password_change. It is the inbuilt authentication feature provided by django. @JerinPeterGeorge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
 url('r^password_change/$',
```

The **r** must be placed before the single quote:

```
 url(r'^password_change/$',
```

Answer (score 2):

Your URL patterns are wrong, i think,
try this

```
urlpatterns = [
    # your other patterns

    url(r'^password_change/$', auth_views.password_change,
        {'post_change_redirect': 'set_goals:password_change_done'},
        name='password_change'),
    url(r'^password_change/done/$',
        auth_views.password_change_done,
        name='password_change_done'),
]
```